# Loading LKM get undefined symbol error

Tags: linux-kernel

when i try to load my Linux kernel module i get an error about an undefined symbol (obviously i get a warning during make). In particular i need to use the macro `pgd_offset_k` in my module (defined in asm/pgtable.h). This is expanded in `pgd_offset(&init_mm, (address))`. The undefined symbol is `init_mm`. I have also verified its presence in /proc/kallsyms:

```
$ cat /proc/kallsyms |grep -w init_mm

c07d49a0 D init_mm
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`init_mm` is not exported past 2.6.29, on the basis that no out-of-tree code should be using it. Can you not do without `pgd_offset_k`?

Comment: Maybe there is a way but i don't know it...i'm trying to do some experiments about virtual -> physical address translation...in particular i would convert an address returned from an ioremap call in the physical address...this convertion should give me the address passed to ioremap (i hope :)). How can i perform this convertion without pgd_offset_k? I think i can't use virt_to_phys because that address is not a logical address right?